# Action Extensions - how do I know when a host app support modification in place?

Tags: ios, share, extension-methods

I'm following a tutorial to create a  simple Action Extension for text. Action extension is triggered as a modal overlay from the “Share…” button in the systemwide text selection context menu (or using the Action button in apps that handle simple text and support it).

The modified are made on a modal overlay handle in a target of your app and at the end of the editing you send back the edited content to the host app (if you want to) and the text is replaced with the edited content. If you send it to an hosted app that don't support modification in place the action don't have effect. My question is: how do I know when an host app supports modification in place?

Here is the code I'm using (derived from [this online tutorial](https://medium.com/@ales.musto/simple-text-action-extension-swift-3-c1ffaf3a197d)).

**Get the items from extension:**

```
 let textItem = self.extensionContext!.inputItems[0]
        as! NSExtensionItem

 let textItemProvider = textItem.attachments![0] // the extension supports text based content so the kUTTypeText UTI is used to perform this test

 if textItemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeText as String) {

        textItemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: // if the host app has data of the required type, it can be loaded into the extension
            kUTTypeText as String,
                                  options: nil,
                                  completionHandler: { (result, error) in
                                    self.receivedText = result as? String // string containing the text loaded from the host app

                                    if self.receivedText != nil {
                                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                            self.processedText = self.receivedText!
                                        } 
                                    }
        })
    }
```

**Returning edited content to the host app:**

```
func returnEditedContent() {
    let returnProvider =
        NSItemProvider(item: processedText as NSSecureCoding?,
                       typeIdentifier: kUTTypeText as String) // create a new NSItemProvider instance

    let returnItem = NSExtensionItem() // a new NSExtensionItem instance is created

    returnItem.attachments = [returnProvider]

    self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [returnItem], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

**Cancel button:**

```
@IBAction func cancelButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.extensionContext!.cancelRequest(withError: DismissExtension.cancelByUser)
}
```

I searched for a solution in various resources without finding it. Here are some documents:

[Apple - Understand Action Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Action.html), [Apple Human Interface Guidelines - Sharing and Actions](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/extensions/sharing-and-actions/), [Medium - Simple Text Action Extension Swift 3](https://medium.com/@ales.musto/simple-text-action-extension-swift-3-c1ffaf3a197d)

Comment: Hello, have you found a solution to this?